# Cannot override view (partial, template, layout) path in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have two custom Extensions: ExtensionA and ExtensionB.
ExtensionB should override/extend ExtensionA.

Simplyfied Setup from ExtensionB:

```
plugin.tx_extensionb {
view {
    templateRootPaths{
        0 = EXT:extensiona/Resources/Private/Templates
        10 = EXT:extensionb/Resources/Private/Templates
    }
    partialRootPaths{
        0 = EXT:extensiona/Resources/Private/Partials
        10 = EXT:extensionb/Resources/Private/Partials
        #20 = EXT:extensionb/Resources/Private/PartialsB/
    }
    layoutRootPaths{
        0 = EXT:extensiona/Resources/Private/Layouts
        10 = EXT:extensionb/Resources/Private/Layouts
    }
  }
}
```

This Snippet is in a Template in ExtensionB:

```
<f:render partial="Assets" arguments="{_all}" />
```

So, first, the Assets.html from ExtensionA should be loaded and, if existing, be overridden by the Assets.html from ExtensionB. Its a bit unusual, but it should work this way.

But there is my problem, TYPO3 take the Assets.html from ExtesionA first, then from ExtensionB if it doesn't exist in ExtensionA. But it should be the other way round. If I remove  plugin.tx_extensionb.partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:extensiona/Resources/Private/Partials, it include the Assets.html from ExtensionB. If I create the Folder "PartialsB" next to Partials, it takes the Assets from PartialsB correctly.
So.. plugin.tx_extensionb.partialRootPaths.10 = EXT:extensionb/Resources/Private/Partials is ignored. same with layouts and templates.

Why? Is this a bug? A "feature"? Is there something I missed? If someone need more Info, just say it.

System: TYPO3 10.4.5. vhs and flux installed.
Static Templates: first all other templates, then extensions, then extensionb.

Comment: And you are sure, this TypoScript is taken into account? Have you checked it via TS Object Browser?

Comment: jep everything is correct via Typoscript object browser. checked it a dozen times. temporarly fixed it just by renaming Partials/ to Partials2/ and setting plugin.tx_extensionb.partialRootPaths.10 = EXT:extensionb/Resources/Private/Partials2. but... this cant be a permanent solution.

Comment: I assume `extensiona` is a public third party extension. Which one is it?

Comment: ExtensionA is a custom extension, too. nothing public. It's kind of a library including assets, basic contenttemplates etc., ExtensionB is site/layoutspezific and has the pageconfig/layout/css/pagetemplates etc. 
ExtensionB extend extensionA, that's why i have to include the templates/partials/layouts from extensionA first and then i should be able to override it with extensionB. (Everything is set up in the extensionB setup.) And thats my problem - this doesn't work. But it is correct in the Typoscript Object Browser.